# iOS TestFlight Build crashing with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an app that uses multiple CocoaPods. I have built at least 10 versions of TestFlight builds with no problems and then one day my app using a new build started crashing when a custom alert view from a CocoaPod was being presented.

I know it has something to do with CocoaPods and TestFlight builds because when I run the app on my iPhone from Xcode, it works perfectly fine with no errors. It just seems to be forgetting that one CocoaPod.

If anyone could provide me with any help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the CocoaPod and reinstalling did the trick!

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. How did you delete CocoaPod? I tried several methods to delete and re-install CocoaPods. None worked for me. Finally, I had to do without the CocoaPods.